# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, deployment

Estoy tratando de compilar una aplicación para Android que está hecha en Xamarin mediante un proyecto compartido para poder transportar la lógica a IOS en un futuro.

Hasta hoy, el proyecto compilaba sin problemas y se instalaba en el emulador (Nexus 5 con Android 5 API 22) sin ningún problema. Sin embargo, desde hace nada, cada vez que trato de instalar el apk en el emulador obtengo el error:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
```

Para que se comprenda mejor, dejo un extracto de la salida de compilación:

```
...
2>TASK: Push bin\Release\CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.CompeticionesPalomosAndroid-Signed.apk : /data/local/tmp/CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.CompeticionesPalomosAndroid-Signed.apk completed?:Completed
2>DEBUG RunShellCommand emulator-5554 pm install "/data/local/tmp/CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.CompeticionesPalomosAndroid-Signed.apk"
2>TASK: InstallPackage pm install "/data/local/tmp/CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.CompeticionesPalomosAndroid-Signed.apk" completed?:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.CompeticionesPalomosAndroid-Signed.apk
2>Failure [I...
2>DEBUG RunShellCommand emulator-5554 rm "/data/local/tmp/CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.CompeticionesPalomosAndroid-Signed.apk"
2>TASK: DeleteFile rm "/data/local/tmp/CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.CompeticionesPalomosAndroid-Signed.apk" completed?:
2> Deployment failed
2>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
2>   en Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) en /Users/builder/data/lanes/5147/c2a33d8e/source/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:línea 333
2>   en Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) en /Users/builder/data/lanes/5147/c2a33d8e/source/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:línea 746
2>   en System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
2>Ejecución de la tarea "InstallPackageAssemblies" terminada.
2>Tarea "Touch"
2>Parámetro de tarea:Files=obj\Release\upload.flag
2>Parámetro de tarea:AlwaysCreate=True
2>Se creará "obj\Release\upload.flag" porque se especificó "AlwaysCreate".
2>Ejecución de la tarea "Touch" terminada.
2>Se omitió la tarea "MakeDir" debido a una condición falsa (False); (!Exists('$(_ConfigurationCacheDirectory)')) se evaluó como (!Exists('obj\.cache\')).
2>Tarea "WriteLinesToFile"
2>Parámetro de tarea:File=obj\.cache\CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.flag
2>Parámetro de tarea:Lines=ReleaseAnyCPU-s emulator-5554
2>Parámetro de tarea:Overwrite=True
2>Ejecución de la tarea "WriteLinesToFile" terminada.
2>Compilación terminada del destino "_Upload" en el proyecto "CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.csproj".
2>Destino "Install" en el archivo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets" del proyecto "C:\Users\Jorge\source\repos\CompeticionesPalomos\CompeticionesPalomosAndroid\CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.csproj" (punto de entrada):
2>Compilación terminada del destino "Install" en el proyecto "CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.csproj".
2>Compilación del proyecto "CompeticionesPalomosAndroid.csproj" terminada.
2>Compilación correcta.
2>Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
2>
2>Error de implementación en Nexus_5_API_22_3
========== Compilar: 1 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
========== Implementar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 omitidos ==========
```

Me parece extraño, pues según esto, la compilación es correcta, pero no se puede implementar. He visto por internet que, en teoria, debe haber algún resto de la aplicación dentro del dispositivo, por lo que directamente he limpiado todo para ver si funcionaba. Sin embargo, no esta funcionando.

La siguiente imagen muestra las referencias:

[image: Referencias del Proyecto]

Por otra parte, esta es la estructura del proyecto completo:

[image: Estructura del Proyecto]

La configuración de compilación es la siguiente:

- Minimum Android Version: Android 5.1 (Nivel de API 22 - Lollipop)
- Target Android Version: Android 5.1 (Nivel de API 22 - Lollipop)
- Compilar con la version de Android: Android 5.1 (Nivel de API 22 - Lollipop)

(Si se necesitase algo más, pedidlo en comentarios y lo añado)

Comment: Que modelo de VS utilizas?

Answer (score -1):

**Este error ocurre cuando intentas instalar una app que no es compatible con la arquitectura de tu emulador.**

- La solución más rápida es descargar el APK compatible con el
  emulador. Si has creado el emulador con arquitectura Intel,
  descárgate el APK para esta arquitectura (no siempre lo hay
  disponible).
- La otra solución, es lo contrario, crear un emulador con arquitectura
  ARM y otro con Intel. Si tienes bastante espacio en tu disco duro, es
  lo que te recomiendo. Así tendrás un emulador Intel y otro ARM. Y
  podrás instalar cualquier app en un emulador u otro dependiendo de su
  arquitectura. Si está construida en Intel, usarás el emulador Intel y
  si está construida en ARM, el emulador ARMv7.

Tocando el código… script **build.gradle**:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

Luego ejecutar en la consola:

```
adb install (TuApp)-x86-debug.apk
```

https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/install_failed_no_matching_abis-android-studio-solucion

---

Tambien lo puedes ajustar editando el fichero **gradle.properties** que está en tu carpeta del proyecto y añadir x86 a PROP_APP_ABI, separadolo mediante "dos puntos (**:**)"

```
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi:x86
```

Comment: El problema en android studio se resolvería así, pero el gradle no está dentro de la arquitectura en Visual Studio Xamarin